# Brute-force algorithm to solve allocation/assignment in Racket

Tags: performance, scheme, racket

The situation: A certain number of kids come to a library and each of them wants to borrow a book. Since there is only one copy of each book in the library, each child must say which book they would like to read the most, which book they like the second most, etc. We assign the books to the kids based on their preferences by trying to minimize the overall "mismatch" score (0 points for kids that get the book they like the most, 1 point for each kid that gets their second most liked book, etc.).

Here is a python script that computes the best way to assign the books to the kids by basically trying all possible combinations with backtracking. It's a very stupid algorithm (the only smart thing it does is to stop searching when it sees that the score for the currently investigated solution cannot become better than the currently known best solution):

```python
# Example with 27 kids.
# Each kid gives a list of 4 books (starting with the most liked book)
preferences=[
    [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [4,9,10,11],
    [12,13,14,15], [16,17,18,19], [20,21,22,23],
    [24,17,4,18], [21,25,26,20], [18,16,17,27],
    [5,13,24,28], [28,3,19,9], [6,17,9,29],
    [30,2,31,14], [27,32,33,25], [17,34,35,5],
    [18,24,17,16], [18,17,35,36], [16,37,38,36],
    [27,9,19,28], [3,39,33,40], [41,38,42,6],
    [17,35,3,30], [43,16,44,23], [38,8,42,5],
    [18,16,3,17], [28,45,46,47], [48,46,17,49]]

# The currently known best solution
bestassignment = []
bestscore = 10000000

# i: the kid we are currently processing
# assignment: the books assigned so far to the kids 0 to i-1
# score: the score calculated so far for the assignment
def search(i, assignment, score):
    global bestassignment, bestscore
    
    if i==len(preferences):   # Preferences of all kids processed?
        if score<bestscore:   # Let's check whether we have found a new best solution.
            bestscore = score
            bestassignment = assignment
    else:
        choices = preferences[i]  # Go through the books chosen by kid #i
        for rank in range(len(choices)):
            choice = choices[rank]
            if choice not in assignment: # Book not already assigned to another kid?
                newscore = score + rank  # Only continue if the score is not  
                if newscore<=bestscore:  # already worse than the best known score.
                    newassignment = assignment + [choice] # Add the book to the list of assigned books.
                    search(i+1, newassignment, newscore)  # Continue with kid i+1.
           
search(0,[],0)
print(f"Score {bestscore} Assignment {bestassignment}")
```

The script works and finds the best solution for the given example in a few seconds. I know there are better algorithms but that's not why I am here. I have tried to write an equivalent Racket program:

```scheme
#lang racket

(define preferences
  '[
    [1 2 3 4]  [5 6 7 8]  [4 9 10 11] 
    [12 13 14 15]  [16 17 18 19]  [20 21 22 23] 
    [24 17 4 18]  [21 25 26 20]  [18 16 17 27] 
    [5 13 24 28]  [28 3 19 9]  [6 17 9 29] 
    [30 2 31 14]  [27 32 33 25]  [17 34 35 5] 
    [18 24 17 16]  [18 17 35 36]  [16 37 38 36] 
    [27 9 19 28]  [3 39 33 40]  [41 38 42 6] 
    [17 35 3 30]  [43 16 44 23]  [38 8 42 5] 
    [18 16 3 17]  [28 45 46 47]  [48 46 17 49]])

(struct solution (score assignment))

(define (search-choices choices preferences score assignment best-solution)
  (for/fold ((new-best-solution best-solution))
            ((choice choices)
             (rank (in-naturals)))
    (cond
      ((member choice assignment)
       new-best-solution)
      (else
       (define newscore (+ score rank))
       (if (<= newscore (solution-score new-best-solution))
           (search preferences newscore (cons choice assignment) new-best-solution)
           new-best-solution)))))

(define (search preferences score assignment best-solution)
  (match preferences
    ((cons choices remaining-preferences)
     (search-choices choices remaining-preferences score assignment best-solution))
    (null
     (if (< score (solution-score best-solution))
         (solution score assignment)
         best-solution))))

(define best-solution (search preferences 0 null (solution 10000000 null)))
(printf "Score ~a Assignment ~a~n"
        (solution-score best-solution)
        (reverse (solution-assignment best-solution)))
```

To my big disappointment, the Racket program is slightly slower than the python script when debugging is activated and just a little bit faster without debugging and stack preservation, even though the python script creates a new list in each iteration.

Am I doing something particularly unidiomatic in the Racket code? Do you have any suggestions for improving its performance? (apart from changing the high-level algorithm, which is the same in both implementations, otherwise it wouldn't be fair to compare them)

Comment: @TobySpeight "the task accomplished by the code"  That's funny because I wanted to title the question "Brute-force algorithm for Allocation problem" but I am not allowed to use the word "problem" in the title although this is the official (mathematical) name for this kind of tasks (e.g. Student-Project Allocation Problem, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that's a bit frustrating.  It's a shame we have to restrict certain keywords from titles, but the alternative is a lot of moderation work for the regulars.  Am I right in thinking it is (or is related to) knapsack-packing algorithms?  (Sorry my Scheme is too rusty to provide a good answer here)

Comment: @TobySpeight  Yes, I think it's related to knapsack-packing. Also the so-called "Student-Project Allocation" problem, I think. There is even a name for precisely this problem but I forgot it even though I read about it two weeks ago :( I know there are more efficient algorithms than my crude solution but my main motivation for posting it here is to get feedback on how to accelerate the Racket code (which is slower than the python one although its back-tracking style implemention should fit perfectly with how Scheme/Lisp implement lists). But thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my re-implementation of the Python code:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(define preferences
  '[
    [1 2 3 4]  [5 6 7 8]  [4 9 10 11]
    [12 13 14 15]  [16 17 18 19]  [20 21 22 23]
    [24 17 4 18]  [21 25 26 20]  [18 16 17 27]
    [5 13 24 28]  [28 3 19 9]  [6 17 9 29]
    [30 2 31 14]  [27 32 33 25]  [17 34 35 5]
    [18 24 17 16]  [18 17 35 36]  [16 37 38 36]
    [27 9 19 28]  [3 39 33 40]  [41 38 42 6]
    [17 35 3 30]  [43 16 44 23]  [38 8 42 5]
    [18 16 3 17]  [28 45 46 47]  [48 46 17 49]])

(define (search preferences)
  (define (do-search preferences score assignment best-score best-assignment)
    (if (null? preferences)
        (if (< score best-score)
            (values score assignment)
            (values best-score best-assignment))
        (for/fold ([best-score best-score]
                   [best-assignment best-assignment])
                  ([choice (in-list (car preferences))]
                   [rank (in-naturals)]
                   #:do [(define new-score (+ score rank))]
                   #:when (and (<= new-score best-score)
                               (not (memv choice assignment))))
          (do-search (cdr preferences)
                     new-score (cons choice assignment)
                     best-score best-assignment))))
  (define-values (score assignment)
    (do-search preferences 0 '() 10000000 '()))
  (values score (reverse assignment)))

(time
 (define-values (score assignment) (search preferences))
 (printf "Score ~S Assignment ~S~%" score assignment))
```

Compared to yours, it keeps the search logic all in one function, uses multiple values instead of a struct to return a best score and assignment values, doesn't use pattern matching, and a few other minor structural differences.

Timings:

```bash
$ racket yours.rkt
Score 14 Assignment (1 5 4 12 16 20 24 21 18 13 28 6 30 27 34 17 36 37 9 39 41 35 43 38 3 45 48)
cpu time: 8500 real time: 8500 gc time: 55
$ racket mine.rkt
Score 14 Assignment (1 5 4 12 16 20 24 21 18 13 28 6 30 27 34 17 36 37 9 39 41 35 43 38 3 45 48)
cpu time: 477 real time: 477 gc time: 15
```

Times are in millseconds. The original python one takes 6.150945925000087 seconds according to `timeit.timeit()`.

I didn't think there were enough differences between yours and mine to account for such a large different in run time, but with some playing around I discovered one huge reason: Your code calls `member`, mine uses `memv` for seeing if a number is present in a list. When I changed that in your version, I got:

```shell
$ racket yours.rkt
Score 14 Assignment (1 5 4 12 16 20 24 21 18 13 28 6 30 27 34 17 36 37 9 39 41 35 43 38 3 45 48)
cpu time: 1016 real time: 1016 gc time: 23
```

Still slower, but much much closer, and lots faster than the Python one. `member` uses `equal?` for comparing values, `memv` uses `eqv?`, which is a simpler function that works fine for comparing numbers and obviously runs a lot faster. `member` does take an optional third argument to use for comparisons, but giving it `=` for explicit numeric equality is, while faster than using `equal?`, still slower than `eqv?`.

Another noticeable speedup comes from using `in-list` in the `for/fold` instead of relying on it to pick the right sequence function at runtime based on the type of `choices`: `(choice (in-list choices))` instead of `(choice choices)` in your `search-choices` function.

Comment: Better late than never?